# Check in php if directory contains different file types

Tags: php, glob

what is the best way, to check if a given directory contains a *.png a *.mp4 and so on?
I only want a true getting returned, if all these filetypes are inside the directory.

This is my current code, which does not work. if I use only one filetype it works, but does not return a false:

```
var_dump(glob($video_dir.'*.txt,.jpg', GLOB_BRACE));
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the code you have tried so far please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// function to find files with specified extensions in a folder
function has_the_files( $dir, $extensions = array() ) { 
    if ( empty( $extensions ) || ! is_array( $extensions ) || ! is_dir( $dir ) ) return false;
    foreach ( $extensions as $ext ) if ( count( glob( $dir . '/*.' . $ext ) ) > 0 ) $found[$ext] = 1;
    return ( count( $found ) == count( $extensions ) ) ? true : false;
}

// use it like
$dir = dirname(__FILE__) . '/images'; //absolute path to the directory you wanna test
$extensions = array('jpg','png'); // an array containing the file extensions you seek for
var_dump( has_the_files( $dir, $extensions ) ); // outputs: bool(false)
```

Answer (score 1):

When using `GLOB_BRACE` you have to use the brackets `{}`. The following code should work:

```
var_dump(glob($video_dir.'{*.txt,*.jpg}', GLOB_BRACE));
```

Comment: Okay. But I want a false getting returned, if one of the file types is missing.

Comment: Ah okay, I see. I think, this won't be possible without looping through your extensions and using `glob()` to find each of them.